# All the Entries are not visible in LineChart

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am using the `LineChart` from  MPAndroidChart library.
I am adding the x value as timestamp which i am converting into date using `IAxisValueFormatter` The issue here is everything is working fine but only one data of the last date is being displayed and the graph ends there. Is there any way of showing all the plotted point on the `LineChart`

Answer (score 0):

I also started using MP Line chart few days ago, encountered the same problem. 
but after prepared Entry data properly it works fine as I want.

suggest you to try with  axis.setAxisMinimum(0.0f);  axis.setAxisMaximum( ??); 
 axis.setLabelCount(??);

```
        ArrayList<String> xVals = setXAxisValues(extraFromDate,extraToDate);
        XAxis axis = mLineChart.getXAxis();
        axis.setAxisMinimum(0.0f);
        axis.setAxisMaximum(((float) mTotalNumberOfDay));
        axis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));
        axis.setLabelCount(xVals.size());
        axis.setGranularity(1f);
        axis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
        axis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        axis.setAxisLineWidth(2f);

        axis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        axis.setDrawGridLines(false);
```

I posted my working code here 
[click here for full code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368771/mpandroidchart-line-chart-how-to-continue-draw-line-till-the-endmax) (sorry my code will be a bit messy, this is my first developing Android app)